# Present data in jquery popup from database using ajax - MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a simple form in asp.net MVC 4. I have a button on it, when click on button i want to open a Jquery popup which contains 2 text boxes, So i want to get data from database and bring into these text boxes. I want a sample code to achieve this or any help would he appreciated. Check out my code. Its working well but not getting data in view, thanks

**View Code below**

```
 @model MvcModalPopup.Models.Person
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <p>This is some content! &nbsp; (@DateTime.Now) </p>
    <button id="model-opener">Open  dialog</button>
    <div id="dialog-model" title="Basic model dialog">

     @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform" }))

        {
            <div>
                <fieldset>

                    <legend>This is legend area</legend>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
                    </div>

                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </p>

                </fieldset>

            </div>
        }

    </div>


    @section scripts{

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#model-opener").click(function(e) {
                    //$("#model-opener").click(function (e) {
                    //alert("Get method run");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    debugger
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/Index",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: {Isclick: false },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#result").html(data);
                            //$("#dialog-model").dialog("close");
                            //$("#dialog").dialog().append(data);
                        },

                        error: function () {
                            alert("Oh noes");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });



        </script>
    }
```

**Controller Code below**

```
public ActionResult Index(bool? Isclick = false)
        {

            Person p = new Person();
            if (Isclick == true)
            {
                p.Id = 1;
                p.FirstName = "James";
                p.LastName = "corner";
            });
            }
            return View(p);

        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code which you have tried and then explain the issue.

Comment: I have edited my question please view...

Comment: Please anyone reply. Iam struggling with this issue